Why do heavy bosons have less range?
Why is it that there's a precise relationship between the mass of a mediator particle and its range? Because mass shouldn't directly affect decay time, right?

What directly affects the ""decay time"" of a virtual boson is not exactly its mass but its energy.
Recall that virtual particles are but interpretations of certain terms in the calculation of the scattering amplitude of a process, with no proper physical meaning; they are said to be "off-shell", because they don't obey momentum-energy dispersion relations. However, they can be assigned a mass, a momentum,or an energy, and in the diagrammatic description of the interaction, a vague notion of "travel time" and range.
The reasoning goes something like this, at least for massive bosons: suppose the virtual particle were a "real" particle. Then the duration of its travel (from being emitted to being absorbed) will allow an uncertainty in its energy satisfying $\Delta E \Delta t \sim\hbar/2$. This means that if you assign this particle an energy (in its rest frame ) of $mc^2$ and assume that the uncertainty is at most of this scale, then you'll have $\Delta t \sim\frac{\hbar}{2mc^2}$. Then, at most, this particle will move at a velocity of $c$, so its displacement in this process will be $\Delta x \sim \frac{\hbar}{2mc}$. Thus we take this as a vague metric of "range" of the associated interaction and put $$R= \frac{\hbar}{mc}$$
I stress the use of the various quotation marks and refer you to this answer.

So is it because the more energy is borrowed from the vacuum, the more unstable the virtual particle?

@Flamethrower I would advise you against thinking in those terms (even though they are  a popular way of framing the question). Virtual particles are not real and as such notions like stability lose their meaning. The vacuum is also the lowest energy state of the system; by definition no energy can be taken from it. A better way of stating this would be something like "the more mass/ energy the virtual particle has, the less time it can travel in a process where its energy uncertainty is of the same scale as its energy". Not as catchy, but more accurate imo.

But why would uncertainty in energy cause the virtual particle to not carry out the interaction?

@Flamethrower it always does so, but in a "maximum time" inversely proportional to its energy uncertainty, hence why the "range" defined above is also inversely proportional to the boson mass.
